# Knockout component binding syntax

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

Is there a custom-element equivalent syntax for the following?

```
<div data-bind="component: { name: 'day-of-week-utilization', params: DayOfWeekUtilization }"></div>
```

When I try the following, my object `DayOfWeekUtilization` isn't passed to my component.  Instead an object with $raw property is passed in.

```
<day-of-week-utilization params="DayOfWeekUtilization"></day-of-week-utilization>
```

My object `DayOfWeekUtilization` has many varying properties, so I don't want to break out the properties within the HTML (needs to be driven by Javascript).  The first syntax works but looks strange in my code because I use custom element syntax everywhere else.

Comment: That will certainly work, but isn't syntactically the same as using the component binding directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `component` binding and custom elements don't work the same way and can't always be substituted for each other. To answer your specific question, as of Knockout 3.4.0, you cannot use the syntax of passing a single `params` object from your viewmodel when using custom elements. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1864) regarding this feature, so maybe it'll be added in the future.

It's probably possible to externally extend the binding provider to support this feature, but that's quite an advanced technique.

Comment: Thanks for referencing the outstanding issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you also add some info about your use-case to the issue?